# Constraint Warning of expected size Auto layout UIScrollView inside a freeform UIViewController

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, autolayout, uistoryboard, nslayoutconstraint

I have a Horizontal UIScrollView in a freeform UIViewController which looks like this

[image]

[image]

and now the warning is that it should update frames 
the expected width is different then what i expect now the problem is that when i run it i always get like a extra half page after the second page if it try to scroll right. it is all problem with constraints

You can see a picture if what exact warning i get[image]

I want to get rid of this warning please.

Thanks in Advance
Aryan